# Uploadify cancel method not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using the Uploadify jQuery plugin for image uploads to my site. I am customising it myself with my own queue markup. Here's the markup:

```
<form id="upload-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="file-queue">
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="upload-form-buttons">
        <input type="file" name="images" id="image-upload" />
        <a href="" class="primary-button">Upload</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the Uploadify code:

```
$('#image-upload').uploadify({
    'swf': '/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
    'buttonClass': 'primary-button',
    'buttonText': 'Select files',
    'height': 28,
    'width': 100,
    'queueID': 'file-queue',
    'overrideEvents': ['onSelect'],
    'onSelect': function(file) {
        onSelect(file);
    },
    'onCancel': function(file) {
        onCancel(file);
    }
});
```

When a file is selected by the user, I'm firing this function to add it to the upload queue:

```
function onSelect(file) {
    // Add the file to the queue
    $('#file-queue ul').append('<li class="' + file.id + '">' + trimName(file.name) + '<a href="javascript:$(\'#image-upload\').uploadify(\'cancel\')"><img class="cancel" src="/img/cancel.png" /></a><span class="filesize">' + readableFileSize(file.size) + '</span></li>');
}
```

The markup for that file comes out as:

```
<li class="SWFUpload_0_0">
    IMG_20120610_185131.jpg
    <a href="javascript:$('#image-upload').uploadify('cancel')">
        <img class="cancel" src="/img/cancel.png">
    </a>
    <span class="filesize">606.1KB</span>
</li>
```

Now, when I click the cancel button, Uploadify does not fire the cancel event. This is the function that should get fired:

```
function onCancel(file) {
    // Remove file from queue
    $('#file-queue ul li.' + file.id).remove();
}
```

but the file never gets removed from the queue. If I put `$('#image-upload').uploadify('cancel')` in my `onSelect` function (I did this as a test), it works. I also tried doing something like `$('img.cancel').live('click', function() { //... });` but it doesn't get fired there either.

Also something that's interesting, if I paste `$('#image-upload').uploadify('cancel');` into the Chrome javascript console while on my page it comes back as `undefined`.

Comment: your chrome console returns undefined because that cancel function doesn't return anything. you can get the same effect by declaring a function in the console.

i got the same problem though, it seems that uploadify has a bug =( did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I ended up using the default Uploadify methods and just using some CSS trickery to style the queue etc. Crappy solution, but the only one that works. :/

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, and solution for me is to put handler in Uploadify callback `onInit`

```
$('#image-upload').uploadify({
    ...
    'onInit': function () {
         $('img.cancel').live('click', function() { //... });
    }
});
```

it works for me, but i actually don't understand, why cancel doesn't fire if handler's set outside Uploadify

Answer (score 0):

I know that onCancel is fired only when setting 'auto' is set to false - so we can see onCancel run only before a file is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

i created new method ,edit jquery.uploadify.js

```
// Create the file data object
        itemData = {
            'fileID'     : file.id,
            'instanceID' : settings.id,
            'fileName'   : fileName,
            'fileSize': fileSize,
            'fullname': file.name // modified by jitheesh 5/1/2017
        }
       // alert(fileName);
        // Create the file item template
        // modified by jitheesh 5/1/2017
        if (settings.itemTemplate == false) {
            settings.itemTemplate = '<div id="${fileID}" class="uploadify-queue-item">\
                <div class="cancel">\
                    <a class="uploadbtn_cancel" rel="${fullname}" href="javascript:$(\'#${instanceID}\').uploadify(\'cancel\', \'${fileID}\')">X</a>\
                </div>\
                <span class="fileName">${fileName} (${fileSize})</span><span class="data"></span>\
                <div class="uploadify-progress">\
                    <div class="uploadify-progress-bar"><!--Progress Bar--></div>\
                </div>\
            </div>';
```

and try this code in your page

```
    $('body').on('click', '.uploadbtn_cancel', function () {

       // alert(this.rel);
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "customers.aspx/RemoveFile",
            data: '{fileName: "' + (this.rel).trim() + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
```